# WCF Webservices and FaultContract - Client's receiving SoapExc insted of FaultException<TDetails>

Tags: wcf, exception, soap, fault

i'm developing a WCF Webservice and consuming it within a mvc2 application.
My problem is that i'm using FaultContracts on my methods with a custom FaultDetail and i'm throwing manyally the faultexception but when the client receive the exception , it receives a normal SoapException instead of my FaultException that i throwed from the service side.

Here is some code:

Custom Fault Detail Class:

```
[DataContract]
public class MyFaultDetails
{
[DataMember]
public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

Operation on service contract:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(MyFaultDetails))]
void ThrowException();
```

Implementation:

```
public void ThrowException()
{
var details = new MyFaultDetails { Message = "Exception Test" };
throw new FaultException<MyFaultDetails >(details , new FaultReason(details .Message), new FaultCode("MyFault"));
}
```

Client side:

```
try
{
// Obv proxy init etc..
service.ThrowException();
}
catch (FaultException<MyFaultDetails> ex)
{
// stuff
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
// stuff
}
```

What i expect is to catch the FaultException , instead that catch is skipped and the next catch is taken with an exception of type SoapException.

Am i missing something ?

i red a lot of threads about using faultcontracts within wcf and what i did seems to be good.
I had a look at the wsdl and xsd generated and they look fine. here's a snippet regarding this method:

```
 <wsdl:operation name="ThrowException">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IAnyJobService/ThrowException" message="tns:IAnyJobService_ThrowException_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IAnyJobService/ThrowExceptionResponse" message="tns:IAnyJobService_ThrowException_OutputMessage" />
      <wsdl:fault wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IAnyJobService/ThrowExceptionMyFaultDetailsFault" name="MyFaultDetailsFault" message="tns:IAnyJobService_ThrowException_MyFaultDetailsFault_FaultMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>

<wsdl:operation name="ThrowException">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IAnyJobService/ThrowException" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
      <wsdl:fault name="MyFaultDetailsFault">
        <soap:fault use="literal" name="MyFaultDetailsFault" namespace="" />
      </wsdl:fault>
    </wsdl:operation>
```

Any help ?

Thanks in advance

Regards

Alessandro

Comment: Your code looks correct at first glance. Are you sure that the SoapException contains your "Exception Test" message, and that it's not actually a 'real' SoapException that occurs before ThrowException() is executed?

Answer (score 3):

Ok guys, solved by myself.
As i said , all was right ... i was just using the wrong httpBinding (basic and not ws).
If u dont use the wsHttpBinding , all the beautiful FaultContract mechanism it's simply not working.

Thanks at all

Regards

Alessandro